# Does Cinema Display daisy chain work in Windows via Bootcamp?

Tags: display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dual Thunderbolt displays with a Mac running Windows under Boot Camp?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48142/dual-thunderbolt-displays-with-a-mac-running-windows-under-boot-camp)

I am wondering if I can have use two Cinema Displays in Windows using daisy chain.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you intend to use two Apple Thunderbolt Displays daisy-chained to a Thunderbolt-equipped computer (whether Mac or not) while the computer is booted into Windows, yes, it should work, assuming whatever drivers are needed are installed and the graphics card has enough power to push two displays' worth of pixels.

tl;dr: If one Thunderbolt monitor works, two identical monitors should work just fine, assuming your graphics card can handle both of them at once.

Comment: I have a MacBook Pro. It runs with two Thunderbolt Displays fine on OSX. Both monitors work in Windows under Parallels too. I just decided to ditch OSX and install Windows but wondering if my both monitors works.

Comment: Can you get one of the monitors working under Boot Camp Windows? If both work under OS X and one works in Windows, then both should work in Windows.

Comment: I didn't try installing Bootcamp yet. I want to make sure then format my drive